# How many points does the perspective in the viewport use and is it changeable?

Tags: 3d-view

I know blender can display both orthographic and perspective projection. But, when we look at a cube in blender's viewport, I'm unable to distinguish by eye, if the projection in the viewport is a one-point, a two-point or a three-point perspective. What does blender use, and is this something changeable?

Comment: Isn't the distinction between one-, two- and threepoint perspective just for drawing? 
Dependent on the camera position, the 3D to 2D perspective projection will give you any of the three...

Comment: @haarigertroll ,  um... blender is basically drawing to the viewport, and the math seems to be different: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~barsky/perspective.html

Comment: It's been a while since I had to calculate transformation matrices, but I think that the math is essentially the same, with just a different series of transformations. Take a look at these (same camera parameters, just different position gives you one, two or three vanishing points) https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKEx1.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZfTe.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PLcI.jpg

Comment: Addendum:
It actually says so on your linked website (last paragraph):
 "Then the matrix for this 3-point perspective is: [...]
And, the 1 point and 2 point perspective matrices are special cases with 1/dx and/or 1/dy equal to zero."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm no architect, but this should only depend on your camera alignment.

- 1 point perspective - camera aligned to 2 axis
- 2 point perspective - camera aligned to 1 axis
- 3 point perspective - camera not aligned to any axis

As given in [the link](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebarsky/perspective.html) in the comment and mentioned by  @haarigertroll mathematically these are special  cases of the one point perspective.

[image]

Comment: Dang! Beat me to it... and nicely illustrated. :)

Comment: Thank you, Robin :).

Comment: But camera angle is the same as object angle to a matrix, so rotating an object will unfortunately break the illusion. :-(